# Directives Necessary to kill this issue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, win-universal-app, entity-framework-core, template10

> C:\Users\mverm\Documents\Projects\Device\XJTResourcesT10\XJTResourcesT10\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(35): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'CreateLambda' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
>
> C:\Users\mverm\Documents\Projects\Device\XJTResourcesT10\XJTResourcesT10\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(91): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'ParameterIsAssignable' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be foound.

I have tried number of items but so far I am not getting anywhere...

This is a UWP application using `Template10, EntityFramework.Sqlite 7.0.0-rc1-final` (For now). When they decide to actually keep us going with actual releases it will change to `EFCore 1.0 variant` once enough pepper is applied..

This will not pass WACK nor will it run correctly as it stands.  Supposedly fixed in current bleeding edge, not worth trying to adapt with constant changes, but this is pushing my deployment back by more than a month with an expected RC2 release based on the Road Maps and mile stones of end of the month... Note: this actually has nothing to do with EF, it remains in release with EF commented out.

tried this so far to no avail...

```
<Type Name="System.Linq.Expressions.Expression" Dynamic="Required Public" />
```

got any insights?

Comment: did you checked reference for System.Linq.Expressions?

Comment: Project.json doesn't directly show but due to dependencies the lock file does have it listed, ah the joys of the new stuff...

Comment: @mvermef - Did you get the problem resolved? I'm getting the same problem in my UWP project.

Comment: nope at a loss, I believe it's an artifact that wasn't dealt with respect to those being private methods and for some reason they are being caught in the compilation to native at that time.  I don't believe any sort of directive will prevent those 2 warnings till the next release which is RC2 of the framework :/, clean application  using Template10 as its template does it

Comment: @mvermef That's a shame! I was hoping for a solution. Supprised it isn't been addressed as it's obviously common but I guess if it doesn't stop you from releasing an app, it's the main thing. Regarding WACK, my previous UWP failed many issues and after contacting Microsoft, they told me not to worry about many of these as they would not stop the release process! Strange, but true and it didn't. I'm just reading an article about continuous integration and guess what, the guy who wrote the articles is getting the same issue, though he's not mentioning issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, but didn't find the answer here.

The short version: upgrade your UWP Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform nuget package to 5.3.x.

For other people running into this, this issue is referenced here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5088 and is (as stated there) solved in an update to .Net Native (that will only work in VS 2017): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/30/announcing-net-core-net-native-and-nuget-updates-in-vs-2017-rc/

HTH

Comment: Note that UWP 5.3.x requires Visual Studio 2017. This fix won't work for people running on 2015.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by running in native debug mode. The problem recently manifested itself to all my archived files so I suspect some update has caused this issue. I fixed it by closing VS2015 then changing the .csproj file for the affected project, from:

```
<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
```

to:

```
<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>false</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While I appreciate the comment, this is not the solution to this... its directly related to a snafu on MS's part, with respect to some methods being marked as public when they were suppose to be private in the assembly related to Linq, reflection goes completely nuts, since they are related to a reflection issue in UWP. Releasing an app now "HAS" to be compiled with Native Tool chain to be placed in store.

Comment: Pity I have not yet submitted as app to the store so thanks for the information. Why has this issue suddenly appeared do you think?

Comment: EF Core is part of it... trying to be bleeding edge doesn't help :(.  UWP is based on a set of newer standards that are part of the "new MS" related to how and what frameworks we will being using, netcorestandard for example is something you will see soon with respect to RC2 of dnx/dnvm and dotnetcli, part of the 1 framework to rule them all... Directives were the way around Reflection issues, this particular one drives Template10 nuts if you compile without a solution LINQ just sits and churs on expressions doesn't know what to do...

Comment: I have an issue related to this tag, when I try to compile my code, It gives an internal compiler error. I de-activated that tag and it worked fine.
But I also noticed the same "System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml" warnings. Do you think this could be related to my problem?